# Side by side boxplots for multilabel data in R?

Tags: r

I am doing exploratory data analysis of the relationship between `goodreads_score` and three boolean independent variables: `fiction`, `best_seller`, and `english`.

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 100
p <- rep(0.5, N)
id <- c(1, N)
fiction <- factor(rbinom(length(p), 1, p))
best_seller <- factor(rbinom(length(p), 1, p))
english <- factor(rbinom(length(p), 1, p))
goodreads_score <- runif(100, 0, 5) 

df <- data.frame(id, fiction, best_seller, english, goodreads_score)
```

I know how to draw the boxplot for one independent variable:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=fiction, y=goodreads_score)) + 
  geom_boxplot(colour = "#3366FF", outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.1, height=0.1))
```

[image]

I wonder if I can put all three labels in one plot(with three side-by-side groups)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may meet your needs:

```
df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, key = category, value = value, 
                     fiction:english, factor_key = TRUE )

ggplot(df2, aes(x=value, y=goodreads_score)) + 
  geom_boxplot(colour = "#3366FF", outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.1, height=0.1)) +
  facet_wrap(~category, scale="free")
```

[image]

If on the other hand, you are looking for grouping of all categories based on indicator values, you can do the following:

```
df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, key = category, value = value, 
                     fiction:english, factor_key = TRUE )

df2$cat_value <- paste0(df2$category,":",df2$value)
df2$cat_value <- factor(df2$cat_value , 
                        levels=c("fiction:0", "best_seller:0", "english:0",
                                 "fiction:1", "best_seller:1", "english:1"))

ggplot(df2, aes(x=cat_value, y=goodreads_score)) + 
  geom_boxplot(colour = "#3366FF", outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=.1, height=0.1)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 3.5, color = "red", linetype = "dashed", size = 1.4)
```

[image]